# How to click on a dynamically created asp tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code that generates a div tag for each image in a folder, and then i want to click the div it created but it dosn't work...

This is my code:

```
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"~/images/avatars"));
for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
{
    string name = Path.GetFileName(images[i]);

    WebControl div = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
    div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "preview-item");
    div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelectAvatar_Click");

    WebControl img = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);
    img.Attributes.Add("class", "item-image");
    img.Attributes.Add("src", @"images\avatars\" + name);

    div.Controls.Add(img);
    avatars.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

avatars is the div that I insert all the dynamiclly generated divs into.

But when i click one of thoes divs nothing happens, although i specified the on click function.

```
protected void SelectAvatar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

the avatars div looks like this:

```
<div id="avatars" runat="server"></div>
```

Maybe im doing it all wrong, or maybe i just don't fully understand how to do it.

So if anybody knows how to do it, it would be great :)

Comment: My advice would be to rethink your approach because you're diving into a hornet nest using that approach. It looks like you're using webforms - so in that situation I'd look towards using a repeater to bind a usercontrol/asp.net controls instead of dynamically creating webcontrols It makes it a lot easier to utilize the webforms event model, viewstate and thereby for example also the click events.

Comment: the onclick you've specified there is a client-side Javascript event. You're creating a standard HTML div, not a server-registered control. For that you'd want to create a Panel (basically ASP.NET's server-side representation of a div). But yeah as above a Repeater control is probably a better way to do the whole thing.

Comment: if you still want to use this approach, take a look at
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink and Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation